# rosjava image_transport example failing

Tags: rosjava, android, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to write a simple app to view the image my robot it will subscribe to the image via a wireless connection to my android phone (not a wifi tether). I started by running the image_transport example on my phone using the eclipse debugger.
I run a bag file on my Ubuntu laptop which publishes the camera/image_raw message and am able to view on another ubuntu pc by setting the ROS_MASTER_URI, however I am unable to view this on my android device connected to the same network running the image_transport example.

The test is using the latest version of the image_transport found at https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android/tutorials/image_transport.  I changed the following lines in the MainActivity.java example file:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RosImageView<CompressedImage> image = (RosImageView<CompressedImage>) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setTopicName("/camera/image_raw");
    image.setMessageClass(org.ros.message.sensor_msgs.CompressedImage.class);
    image.setMessageToBitmapCallable(new BitmapFromCompressedImage());
    try {
      // TODO(damonkohler): The master needs to be set via some sort of
      // NodeConfiguration builder.
      nodeRunner.run(image,
          Lists.newArrayList("Compressed", "__ip:=192.168.1.100", "__master:=http://192.168.1.123:11311/"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

No errors are reported, and the app pops up on the phone, but no image is displayed. The image in the message (sensor_msgs/Image) is black and white and 320x260.

I filtered logcat for image_transport during one of the attempts:

I/ActivityManager(  173): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.ros.tutorials.image_transport/.MainActivity } from pid 270
I/ActivityManager(  173): Displayed org.ros.tutorials.image_transport/.MainActivity: +289ms (total +1s717ms)

Is there anything that I could be doing wrong?

Tested on:

Motorola Droid
OS: Android 2.3 (cyanogen mod 7.0.3)

HTC Incredible
OS: Android 2.3 (cyanogen mod 7.0.3)

Laptops running ubuntu 10.4 and 10.10 with diamondback installed

::
UPDATE
In a second attempt I changed the message to /camera/image_raw/compressed and the image still would not show up, which seem to be unrelated to the change to the message.

in logcat there is an error:
the E/UpdatePublisherRunnable( 2697): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu-laptop

roswtf shows that the imagetransport node created by the phone should be connected but isn't.

Are there any specific network settings that are needed? I added the laptop I was connecting to the host file of the android device.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10037/rosjava-image_transport-example-failing/) by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-24**:
And does anything show up in logcat?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-23**:
Do you see any errors on your Ubuntu system? What is the message type of your /camera/image_raw topic in the bagfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should try setting the ROS_IP environment variable on your laptop. It sounds like the phone is having trouble finding the laptop by hostname.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar issue at first. The image_transport example does not automatically subscribe to the compressed image topic, as normal image_transport does.

Change the topic you are subscribing to to one that has a type `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage` such as `/camera/image_raw/compressed` and then it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) on 2011-05-27**:
In a second attempt I changed the message to /camera/image_raw/compressed and still had some problems viewing the image: